# Unable to execute/run any vhdl code using ghdl

Tags: vhdl, file-permissions, ghdl

I have installed ghdl in Ubuntu 10.10 (using apt-get from the repository) and used the hello_world example available in the ghdl manual. I can analyze (-a) and elaborate (-e) successfully but when I try to run/execute (-r) it, I get the following error:
/usr/lib/ghdl/bin/ghdl: compilation error

To elaborate my problem, I have mentioned the vhdl code at the end and the sequence of commands that I follow below:

> $ ghdl -a hello.vhdl
>   $ ghdl -e hello_world
>   $ ./hello_world
>   bash: ./hello_world: Permission denied
>   $ ghdl -r hello_world
>   /usr/lib/ghdl/bin/ghdl: compilation error

I have tried working as root too but without success. The permissions are perfect, the execute bit is set. Everything seems to be fine, but still it doesnt work. I have even tried reinstalling the ghdl package.

Can someone please tell me what could be the source of problem?

Thanks in advance.

hello.vhdl (Vhdl code)

> -- Hello world program.
>   use std.textio.all; -- Imports the standard textio package.
>   -- Defines a design entity, without any ports.
>   entity hello_world is
>   end hello_world;
>   architecture behaviour of hello_world is
>   begin
>       process
>       variable l : line;
>       begin
>           write (l, String'("Hello world!"));
>           writeline (output, l);
>           wait;
>       end process;
>   end behaviour;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your filesystem mounted noexec?  What does `mount` say about the filesystem that your working area is one?

Comment: Got it! The mount did not have exec set!! With the partition now having exec permission, ghdl works fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Now the question is does that count as a shot in the dark or was it provided from personal experience?  And with a little malice of forethought, chmod -x scan_tb; ghdl -r scan_tb gives: `ghdl: compilation error` (and isn't particularly descriptive).

Comment: @DavidKoontz - it was a long time ago, but I imagine  it was a shot in the dark (certainly I've not had that specific problem with GHDL, although I've had it when trying to run other executables off a memory-stick device which was mounted noexec).

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the problem if the execute bit is not set.

Are you absolutely sure there is no problem with permissions?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about this. Output of "ls -al hello_world" is
"-rwxr-xr-x 1 neel neel 447332 2011-01-25 12:16 hello_world"

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, and my solution which seemed to have fixed everything was to chmod the /usr/local/bin/ghdl folder with 777 mod.